# BPEL Engine for .NET platform

Tags: .net, workflow, bpel

There are any open source BPEL based workflow engine for .net?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an open source alternative, you can go for [WSO2 BPS](http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server/) or [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/).
The BPEL processes deployed in these servers, exposed as web services, so that processes can be accessed from .Net by invoking the respective web service.

Answer (score 1):

I think Biztalk server 2010 could serve you.